# API Controller blocks WebServer - with same design

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-3.0

I am about to build an MVC API server with asp.net core 3.1.

I have two API controllers next to the default one (provided by code example).

- WeatherController -- code example
- ReservationController -- generated
- UserController -- manually constructed

**Issue Description:**

1. calling WeatherController - GET method --> returns properly
2. calling ReservationController - GET method --> returns properly
3. calling UserController - GET method --> fails and REST client returns "ErrorinAPI" message
4. calling ReservationController - GET method --> returns slowly (blocked until 3rd call times out)

Logging is on, but apparently the request does not even hit the UserController. (debug mode does not enter, no log messages are recorded on given method).

- I have tried to change the Route definition to be exact [Route("user")], but no difference.
- I have tried to change UserController GET method to return a simple string instead of IActionResult - no change.
  Any suggestions are welcome as I kinda fail to see the difference or the mistake.

Reservation Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Reservation : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

UserController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class User : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Something returned");
    }
}
```

For reference the Startup.cs related content:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // Adding Serilog as logger service
            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHsts();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: normally the convention you should call User as UsersController and so on.

Comment: Oddly enough if I recreate the controller with - right click - add new item - controller - empty controller. Copying the above example works.. So might it happen that in asp.net core 3.1 some references are added to csproj? or.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you manually constructed it. Do you mean you merely created a class a typed/copied that stuff in?

Have you tried to right click and add new controller and add it that way? When I see ApiController, I think more Web Api, not Controller (MVC) but I don't normally create them manually.

Also, can you try changing your route on the actual controller to [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

I am not honestly sure whether your controller is being properly registered or not but sometimes manually creating the controllers acts up.

Also one controller action should not block another one like that, so I would be curious as to your client. Is it just doing a loop or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename classes:

```
public class Reservation : ControllerBase
```

to

```
public class ReservationController : ControllerBase
```

and

```
public class User : ControllerBase
```

to

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
```